# any suggest? Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]

Tags: android, sdk, android-manifest, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

my build.gradle:
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.vladxd.trackingpoint_2"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
}
```

and here is my Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.vladxd.trackingpoint" >

    <!-- To access Google+ APIs: -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.vladxd.trackingpoint.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyB5HcvlWp6AAUBU65Iq7CC_huQi_yK1XG8" />


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Do u have any idea how I can solve it? I've try to find this problem on another post from stackoverflow but all that don't work for me... and I don't know why.
So if u have any idea pls told me :D

Sry for my bad english.

Comment: err code:  pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.vladxd.trackingpoint_2
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]

Answer (score 0):

The gradle file sets the build to be minSdk of 21 which is Android 5.0. The error is basically saying that the device you're attempting to install on has an older os.

If go into the device settings -> About Phone there should be an entry that shows your Android Version. That should then line up with the values from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html

Comment: yeah this may be reason

Comment: Thx man :D u have right, I've don't set Android version, ty :)